# How to add the variable from context in keyconditions aws cdk appsync

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, vtl

How can I provide the `id` variable from `context.args` in the following code:

```
requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbQuery(appsync.KeyCondition.eq("id", )
```

I know how to get it in VTL, but I cannot find any example of adding the variable in `appsync.KeyCondition.eq` without using VTL.

Here's my schema:

```
type Mutation {
  createTodo(todo: String!): Todo!
}

type Query {
  getTodo(id: String!): Todo
  allTodos: [Todo!]
}

type Todo {
  id: String!
  todo: String!
  isCompleted: Boolean!
}
```

I tried to add the variable in string,

```
 requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbQuery(
    appsync.KeyCondition.eq("id", "$ctx.args.id")
  ),
```

but it generated this code:
[image]

Comment: it's in this code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/5940/files#diff-4e7c1a79970da74f466e8965e3c465af0fd63423ca2a772a51923e1e843c40b0R462

```ts
    public renderExpressionValues(): string {
        return this.args()
            .map((arg: string) => {
                return `":${arg}" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.${arg})`;
            })
            .join(", ");
    }
```

in your case, you'd just need to pass in 'id'.